# Replacing virtual method of existing Gtk object in python

Tags: python, gtk, overriding, virtual

My program has a DrawingArea which comes out of a UI file and is already existing when I want to replace get_preferred_height_for_width() of it.

My goal is to get a fixed aspect ratio of a child window (DrawingArea).

I've already tried [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance) but that does not seem to work. I can call the overridden function of the object by myself, but Gtk does not call it.

There must be a way to attach get_preferred_height_for_width behaviour to an existing Gtk object which comes out of a UI file.

What am I doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: I used Gtk.AspectFrame now. Seems to work ;)

Comment: Then please post it as a answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I used Gtk.AspectFrame now. Seems to work ;)